# How to Calculate the region in $u$-$v$ plane in transformation of variables?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Here is a question on Integrals :

Use the transformation $u^2 - v^2 =x$ , $y = 2uv$ to calculate the integral

$$ \int_0^1\int_0^{2\sqrt{1-x}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,dy\,dx,$$

Now I have calculated the region  corresponding to $u$-$v$ plane is given by:

$u =0 ,v = 0 , u = \pm v, u = \pm 1$ However this region is present in all Four quadrants of $u$-$v$ plane

I am confused which region  should  I work with to calculate this double integral ?

Can anyone please help me here ?

Thank you.

Comment: $u^2 - v^2 =x?$

Comment: @user:Ah yes ! Thanks for noticing the typo.

Comment: The expression $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\sqrt{1-x}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,dx$ does not make sense. Are you sure you don't need $\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_0^{2\sqrt{1-x}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,dy\,dx $ instead of $$ \int_0^1\int_0^{2\sqrt{1-x}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,dx\,dy \text{ ?} $$